# Do Delphi IDEs have a project/grouproject's file count and line count functionality?

Tags: delphi, delphi-ide

Do any Delphi IDE versions provide functionality that gives the total line count and file count of a given project group (or at least of a single project)?

If no, are there any IDE add-on tools that add this feature?

Comment: Noticed "information for [project]" in project menu?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: I checked if it was what I was looking for but it's always disabled, I've updated the question by adding this information.

Comment: Have you tried to compile\build the project, and after that check for "Information for project"?

Comment: @RBA: You're right, now I've noticed that these informations are discarded each time the IDE is closed or another project is compiled/built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu "Information for [project]" will be available as soon as a project is compiled/built.

Another way is to enable `Show compiler progress`.

You can set it in [Tools/Options/Environment options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Environment_Options).

Answer (score 2):

That information will be available after you'll compile/build your project. Take a look at [Information for Project](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Information)

More in depth informations about LoC(lines of code) you can find on this SO post [LoC (lines of code) metrics for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421058/loc-lines-of-code-metrics-for-delphi)